# find does not give expected answer

Tags: find

How is this possible:

```
$ find ACCESS -name arctic20.xml
```

gives no output, but:

```
$ ls -l ACCESS/arctic20.xml
```

gives:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 damocles damocles 2286 Nov  2  2016 ACCESS/arctic20.xml
```

I checked the file name for invisible characters, but found nothing:

```
$ ls -1 ACCESS/arctic20.xml | od -c
0000000   A   C   C   E   S   S   /   a   r   c   t   i   c   2   0   .
0000020   x   m   l  \n
0000024
```

This is my system:

```
$ uname -a
Linux adc-a 3.13.0-115-generic #162-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 24 16:03:51 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't just have a typo while doing that command? Because it should just show you as output `ACCESS/arctic20.xml` or maybe you weren't in the right directory, might aswell try full paths instead of relatives and see how that goes.

Comment: Is ACCESS a directory, or is it a symlink to a directory?

Comment: No typo. The commands shown are copy and pasted from my terminal. The two commands were submitted from the same directory, and ACCESS is a subdirectory of this directory. Anyway, thanks for your interest.

Comment: AlexP, you are right! ACCESS was a symlink to another directory. I was sure it was a proper directory, but since you asked, I took another look just now. Thank you. Problem solved.

Comment: @Zanna: OK, done.

Answer (score 1):

By default, GNU `find` does not follow symbolic links, not even when considering command-line arguments. From [`man find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/find.1.html):

> The `-H`, `-L` and `-P` options control  the  treatment  of  symbolic  links. Command-line  arguments  following these are taken to be names of files or directories to be examined, up to the  first  argument  that  begins with  `'-'`, or the argument `'('` or `'!'`.
>
> `-P` Never follow symbolic links.  *This  is  the  default  behaviour.*  When find examines or prints information a file, and the file is a symbolic link, the information used shall be  taken  from  the properties of the symbolic link itself.

If `ACCESS` is (or may be) a symbolic link to a directory and you want to find files inside even if is *is* a symbolic link then you must say `find -H ACCESS`.